# Issue setting up web.config in .NET to integrate Angular for client side

Tags: .net, angular, localhost, web-config

I set up the IIS manager accordingly, which points to my wwwroot folder and IIS_IUSRS is added in Groups.
I set up my web.config as the following.
Not sure why I keep getting either insufficient permissions or localhost loads indefinitely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="NetFramework" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      
      <!-- bunch more handlers here-->
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  </location>
      
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <!-- Static file serving settings -->  
    <staticContent>
      <!-- Add MIME type mappings for common Angular file types -->
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <!-- bunch more extensions here -->
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```